# R - How to print more than three tables on one page in a PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to create a multiple page PDF file from R which contains both data.frames and ggplots. I managed to do so transforming the data.frames into grobs and using the grid.arrange function.

The problem I have now is that I want to print five tables/grobs on the first page in the PDF, one below another. On page 2 I want only one table as it contains different kinds of data. Page 3 will contain a ggplot. It works perfectly fine to put up to three tables on one page but as soon as I try it with four or more it will print them in two columns and they will overlap.

Here is what I tried up to now:

```
# Load required packages
library(gridBase)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

# Transform tables into grobs
Table1 <- tableGrob(df1)
Table2 <- tableGrob(df2)
Table3 <- tableGrob(df3)
Table4 <- tableGrob(df4)
Table5 <- tableGrob(df5)
Table6 <- tableGrob(df6)

# Create the PDF file

pdf("file.pdf", height = 15, width = 20)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 1, 6, byrow = TRUE))
grid.arrange(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5)
grid.arrange(Table6)
grid.arrange(ggplot1)
dev.off()
```

Does anybody know where I'm wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers,
Tilman

[This is what the first page of the PDF looks like as soon as I use more than three tables. I want them to be all in one column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlVAY.png)

Comment: just as a comment: if you're drawing only one grob it's better to use `grid.draw(Table6)` than `grid.arrange(Table6)` (and same for ggplot1). `grid.arrange()` only makes sense for multiple grobs, otherwise you're adding unnecessary complexity to the graphic with unused layouts.

Answer (score 4):

Just solved it - and of course there's an easy solution I did not think about.

```
grid.arrange(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, ncol = 1, nrow = 5)
```

Just adding ncol and nrow makes the deal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using or looking up variations of the `\newpage` function? That goes outside of a chunk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I tried but it will give me the same result as before. I think this is not really what I'm looking for as I already have the number of pages that I want just by using new grid.arrange() commands. What I want is to gather the first five tables on one and the same page.

Comment: Just added a picture of the first page of the PDF output with data from mtcars